# Google App Engine CSS Problem

Tags: css, google-app-engine

I have a strange problem with css file in google app engine.
If i use

---

**handlers:**

```
- url: /cms/.* script: cms.py

- url: /
  script: main.py

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

---

in my `app.yaml` file for http://localhost:8080/ it works fine.
But when i redirect it to another handler in `main.py` It gives such an error

```
Not found error: /login did not match any patterns in application configuration.
```

When I use this

---

**handlers:**

```
- url: /cms/.* script: cms.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py


- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

---

whole logic works just fine ( no error occurs wherever I roam in the application) but no sign of css this time.
I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /cms/.* 
  script: cms.py

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Your first solution does not work with `/login` because using `/`  you are getting just the root
Your second solution does not work because `stylesheets` cames after the catch all pattern `.*`

Comment: Thank you so much, I just discovered it. I was about to answer the question, i saw your answer.

Comment: @gurkan you are welcome, sometime just writing a question is helpful to catch an error :)